# Android App not vibrating outside of app

Tags: php, android

I have a little problem: If I send a notification to my android device via php from the web, a notification gets built, but isn't vibrating outside the app. It is only vibrating while I am inside the app.

Here are my codes:

PHP:

```
function  send_notification ($token, $message, $Raum, $Notruf){
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => array('body' => "Raum ".$Raum.", Notruf ".$Notruf), 'data' => array ('message' => $message));
        $headers = array ('Authorization:key = (HERE IS MY AUTH KEY)','Content-Type: application/json');

        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result == FALSE) {
            die ('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

        $sql = 'SELECT token FROM devices as d, Sani as s WHERE d.sean = s.sean AND s.Status!=0';

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $tokens = array ();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $tokens[] = $row["token"];
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($db);

    $message = array ("message" => "Raum ".$Raum.", Notruf ".$Notruf);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tokens); ++$i) {
        $message_status = send_notification ($tokens[$i], $message, $Raum, $Notruf);
        echo $message_status;
    }
```

My Android Notification Code:

```
public class MyNotificationManager {

    private Context mCtx;
    private static MyNotificationManager mInstance;

    private MyNotificationManager(Context context){
        mCtx=context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyNotificationManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance== null){
            mInstance = new MyNotificationManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void displayNotification(String title, String body){

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sirenlight)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setVibrate(new long[] {0, 5000, 100, 5000, 100, 5000, 100, 5000, 100, 5000, 100, 5000})
                .setContentText(body);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, EinsatzInterface.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if(mNotificationManager!=null){
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }

    }

}
```

I couldn't get any fixes online, so I am asking here.
How I said, the vibration is working, but only inside the app. If I close it, even without stopping the process, it only shows the notification and doesn't vibrate or show the correct logo.

[When inside the app the notification looks like this (vibrating and icon showing):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFm7R.png)

[When outside the app the notification looks like this (not vibrating and icon not showing):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHItr.png)

Comment: First check `displayNotification` is gettinf called or not . Its not getting called. If you are using FCM then see  [FCM Mesages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: wakeup cpu before building the notification. for example :

PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();

Comment: @ADM It might not get called, but when I am inside the app the vibration is used.